# flask render_template return ascii code for string

Tags: python, json, flask

The content of "test.html" is

```
{{data}}
```

When I render it using

```
render_template('test.html',data=u'{"a":12,"b":34}')
```

the result is

```
{& #34;a& #34;:12,& #34;b& #34;:34} //I add whitespace between & and # for display
```

When I render it with

```
render_template_string('{{data}}',data=u'{"a":12,"b":34}')
```

the result is

```
{"a":12,"b":34}
```

It's difficult to deal with the 1st result string with `JSON.parse()` in JavaScript. Is that a bug of flask? Or did I deal with it in a wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `render_template`, Jinja automatically escapes the string. To stop that, use the `safe` filter:

```
{{ data|safe }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when loading from the file the values will be escaped, and this is expected.  What I'd recommend, however, is that if you are looking to return JSON do the following instead, as an example:

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/get_data')
def get_data():
    return jsonify({"a":12,"b":34})
```

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.json.jsonify