# python flask mlab js unicode stange behaviour

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, unicode, mlab

I'm trying to retrieve some data from a mongodb hosted on mlab.com and to use this data in a template as jinja2 variable.

When I try to console.log data dict sent from flask `"` char is shown as `&#39;` and I can't find keys and values inside the dictonary.

Anybody had the same issue?

[`u&#39;`My precious data `&#39;`] insted of ['My precious data']

---

Backend (flask)

```
if not session.get('logged_in'):        
    return 'Please login'
else:
    restaurant = mongo.db.restaurant
    restaurantData = list(restaurant.find())
    logging_wrap1.debug(restaurantData)
    import json
    d = json.dumps(restaurantData[0])
    logging_wrap1.debug('This is d : %s',d)
    return render_template('customer.html', data = d )
```

Frontend

```
console.log('{{data}}')
```

Console output
`[{u&#39;description&#39;: u&#39;cel mai bun restaurant&#39;, u&#39;icon&#39;: u&#39;Some img will be saved here&#39;, u&#39;location&#39;: u&#39;46.5407567,23.8916893&#39;, u&#39;_id&#39;: u&#39;xxxx&#39;, u&#39;open&#39;: {u&#39;weekend&#39;: u&#39;Closed&#39;, u&#39;weekday&#39;: u&#39;0800-1800&#39;}, u&#39;name&#39;: u&#39;broscuta&#39;}]`

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35159807/5320906)

Comment: @snakecharmerb you are right. After reading the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35159807/6483963) you told me and takeing a closer look at my code, just adding the ```|safe``` filter after ```data``` solves my problem. Thank you